# What's the difference between Sony NEX 5R and NEX 5T?

Tags: sony, sony-nex

I saw Sony has a newer model - 5T. What's the difference between Sony NEX 5R and NEX 5T? Is it only the NFC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find two differences:

1. NFC
2. Price

An extended discussion, filled mostly with rants can be found here: http://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3543188#forum-post-52117675

Comment: Perhaps you could at least expand your answer enough to define what NFC abbreviates.

Comment: NFC is a pretty common technology nowadays....it means Near-Field Communication